# In ibm watson conversation, How to extract a string after a certain word into the context variable?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

for e.g. "show me an image of Eiffel tower" ... so i want Eiffel tower to be stored in the variable. that is i want any word after "of" to be stored. how to do this? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code you already have?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is by creating an entity which contains values like Eiffel Tower. Then you can store that in any context variable.

```
{
  "context": {
    "xyz":"@Place"
  },
  "output": {}
}
```

Here Place is your entity.You can use your context variable anywhere.

Comment: then how would i do this -  " show me the imdb rating of iron man"... want that movie name "iron man" to be stored in a variable

Comment: U need to create a entity of movie names.

Comment: no i am not. This is the right way to do this.Your method is incorrect.Suppose if your text contains 2 times "of" then what will u do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regular expressions** to capture entity values from user input. To capture the one or two words after *of*, use `of ([a-z]+\s*[a-z]+)` as the regular expression. Regular expressions are called patterns in WCS. Here is how a definition could look:

[image: entity recognition using regular expressions]

Then save the what the user says into the context variable using:

```
{
  "context": {
    "thing": "<? @thing.groups[1] ?>"
  }
}
```

To test it you can use the context variable in an answer, for example:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Getting a picture of $thing"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

More information can be found at: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities